# Hi i have been trying to use CheckBoxListTile in Flutter

Tags: flutter

```
          child: CheckboxListTile(
          title: Text('Eggs'),
          controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.platform,
          value: _checked,
          onChanged: (bool value){
            setState(() {
              _checked = value;
            });
          },
          activeColor: Colors.white,
          checkColor: Colors.red[900],
        ),
```

This is the code i used. The error is showing at the _checked. It says that _checked is not defined. A new user to flutter here.

Comment: did you initialize the `_checked ` variable @User1234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually need to initialize a variable in the beginning.
Maybe you can do it by initializing it like:

```
bool _value = true //or false according to your program
```

or you can do this in the screen's or page's:

```
 class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return CheckboxListTile(
          title: const Text('Animate Slowly'),
          value: timeDilation != 1.0,
          onChanged: (bool value) {
            setState(() {
              timeDilation = value ? 10.0 : 1.0;
            });
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

Basically, you are getting this error as you haven't initialized `_checked` variable.

Comment: your welcome. I am happy that it helped you. if so click on that tick on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> It says that _checked is not defined

You properly miss to define `_checked`.

```
bool _checked = false;
```